# Anet A6 Firmware

Tags: marlin, firmware, anet-a6

I've just finished putting my new Anet A6 together. Very nice build all together as everything fits really well.

I've tried a test print and I noticed something weird: as I try to home ONLY the Z axis to level the bed, the printer automatically moves the nozzle to the X0 Y0 after doing the Z0 first. It doesn't make a difference whether I do it on Octoprint Control or sending the G-Code, so it appears to be a Firmware thing. Why is the Firmware programmed like this is something I'd like to know because it makes the levelling of the bed a nightmare.

That's why I wanted to update the Firmware and here is where I got confused... seems that the Firmware used for this boards is something called Skynet3d. I went to their Github page and all they have are 3 section as follows:

1. A board profile for the Arduino IDE
2. What looks like the normal Marlin Firmware
3. Skynet3d Firmware, which is empty.

Inside section 2, all I see is a normal group of files corresponding to the Marlin Firmware and some configuration.h examples: they have one for the Anet A8 but not for the Anet A6

So, summing up my question is: *Where do I find the A6 Firmware?* I've seen a Youtube video of a guy with the A6 profiles, but I don't know the official source of them...

Does somebody know?

Comment: Is your initial problem similar to what is described here? https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4225/lack-of-isolation-between-axes I realise this doesn't answer your question, but might make sense of the scenario.

Comment: Its hard to visualise your problem. So you dont think the original homing system is correct or?

Answer (score 5):

Skynet3D is an obsolete [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)) of [Marlin Firmware](http://marlinfw.org/) that was created because the displays of the Anet printers have a different layout in terms of pin assignment. When the code stabilized, the fork of Marlin merged into the main code base. Configuration files for the Anet A8 and A6 have been added, see [here](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/tree/1.1.x/Marlin/example_configurations/Anet/A6) for the A6, so when you flash Marlin to your board, be sure to copy these configuration files to the root code directory.

An overview of all active printer firmwares is given by *www.reprap.org* at [List of Firmware](https://www.reprap.org/wiki/List_of_Firmware).