# Trouble uploading Skynet3D to my Anet A8 via Arduino program

Tags: firmware, skynet3d

I'm in distress here fellow people. I'm a noob to 3d printers and want to become an expert. Everybody has to start at the bottom right? Like the title says I'm trying to upload Skynet to my printer and for the board, I'm selecting `V.1` even though my arduino board says `V.1-5`. And for port I'm selecting `COM3`, which is information I found in device manager, and the file I'm selecting to upload is `SkynetV.1.?alfa.ino`. After all of that is selected I click upload and I get the following error messages:

```
Sketch uses 114,230 bytes (87%) of program storage space. Maximum is 131,072 bytes.
Global variables use 4,470 bytes of dynamic memory.
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd6
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x80
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xae
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd6
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x02
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x21
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcc
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd6
```

Please help me.

Comment: have you tried anything from this list: http://www.instructables.com/id/A-solution-to-avrdude-stk500getsync-not-in-syn/ ?

Comment: Please read: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/anet-a6-firmware and go for Marlin (although it is the A6, it also applies to the A8)

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a screenshot of the device manager, in particular `COM3`? Are you sure that you have the correct drivers installed? *Or* if you have fixed your problem, could you post the solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*Skynet3D was a very old fork from Marlin firmware, all functionality (more specifically for the odd LCD screens used by Anet) have been merged into Marlin firmware. Just get the latest version of Marlin. The current and final release of branch 1.1.x is 1.1.9 further development will be done in 2.0.x. Version 1.1.9 works perfectly fine for the Anet A8.*

---

These error messages are displayed when you have either selected the wrong COM port or wrong Arduino board or have faulty or no drivers installed.